# pgfplot dateplot discrete dates on axis

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

With `pgfplot` using `dateplot` when plotting data over a small date range, some dates are shown multiple times to "fill" the horizontal axis. I wonder if it is possible to show only discrete dates. Since I automate the generation of figures I don't want to set the ticks manually.

Here my working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,value
2015-01-01, 3.2
2015-01-02, 6.5
2015-01-04, 6.8
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\day-\month-\year},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    date ZERO=2015-01-01,
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Date (day-month-year)},
    ylabel={Value},
]
\addplot table [x=date, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would `xtick=data` be an option?

Comment: I though of that as well, however the dates are then not continues (03-01-2015 will disappear)

Comment: This question is not directly related to `dateplot`, the problem also occurs for plotting with integers instead of dates. Should I change this question or ask a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to adapt the solution from [pgfplot discrete integers on axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286609/pgfplot-discrete-integers-on-axis) to define a macro with the `tick` label embedded in it and suppress the tick if that macro is already defined:

[image]

### Related Question:

- [pgfplot discrete integers on axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286609/pgfplot-discrete-integers-on-axis)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,value
2015-01-01, 3.2
2015-01-02, 6.5
2015-01-04, 6.8
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\day-\month-\year},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    date ZERO=2015-01-01,
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Date (day-month-year)},
    ylabel={Value},
    xticklabel={%
        \ifcsdef{Tick Used \tick}{}{%
            \tick%
            \csxdef{Tick Used \tick}{}%
        }%
    },  
]
\addplot table [x=date, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for day-month-year notation I'd to change `\tick%` into `\day-\month-\year`

Comment: I have a follow-up question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288338/forget-used-ticks

Comment: Why is `xticklabel` defined twice?

Comment: @koppor: Oversight on my part. Don't think the first one is needed.

Comment: In case one gets `Could not parse input '2015-01-01' as a floating point number, sorry`, one has probably forgotten to add `\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}`.